# Serial port not reading all data

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, protobuf-net

I have a microcontroller (Arduino Uno) running nanopb that is sending protobuf messages over the wire.  I'm finding that under one specific case I'm not receiving my full message.  I thought for a while that it was the microcontroller, but it appears to be on the C# side that's reading from it.

The issue ONLY happens for uint32 values GREATER THAN 16.  16 or less and it works fine.

I've setup a VERY simple program on the microcontroller to ensure it's not my other code that's causing it there.  Essentially it's sending a struct over the wire with one uint32_t value in it:

```
//Protobuf message:
message Test { required uint32 testInt = 1 }

//Resulting struct:
typedef struct Test {
    uint32_t testInt;
}

//Serial code:
Serial.begin(115200);
pb_ostream_t ostream;

//Removed ostream setup code as it's not relevant here...

Test message;
Test.testInt = 17;
pb_encode_delimited(&ostream, Test_fields, &message);
```

If I plug in my device and look at it's data output using [Termite](http://www.compuphase.com/software_termite.htm) I see the following data (which is correct):

```
[02] [08] [11] (note Termite displays it in hex)
```

(That's saying the message is 2 bytes long, followed by the msg start byte, followed by the Test.testInt value of 17 - 0x11 in hex)

Now, if I bring this up in C# I should see 3 bytes when reading the message, but I only see 2.  When the value in testInt is 16 or less it comes across as three bytes, 17 or greater and I only get two:

```
var port = new SerialPort("COM7", 115200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
port.Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSendXOnXOff;
port.Open();
while (port.IsOpen)
{
    Console.WriteLine(port.ReadByte());
    Thread.Sleep(10);
}
port.Close();
Console.ReadLine();

Output with 16: 2 8 16
Output with 17: 2 8 17
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I'm at a loss on this one =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the serial port to use Xon/Xoff. Why?

The code for XON is 17.

If you are sending binary data, don't use Xon/Xoff.

Comment: BINGO - geez that was driving me BONKERS...I was using Xon/Xoff for handshaking, but it looks like I'll need to use a different process instead

Comment: Yeah, nobody has used Xon/XOff since we stopped using teletypes :) `serialPort.RtsEnable = true` is what I used with my Arduino devices.

Comment: If you need flow control and cannot use HW handshake, then (with extra effort) XON/XOFF can still be used with binary data, but you you need a method of *escaping* data values of 0x11 and 0x13.

Comment: @IanMercer yeah I wound up with `DtrEnable = true` - I'll do some research into whether or not it's gonna cause me any issues - thanks again though, you're a life saver.  @sawdust yeah I'm sure I could, but following KISS it's probably best to just leave it off haha

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a simple race condition - there is nothing to ensure that the C# code gets 3 bytes. It could get one, two, three or more. If, say, it starts the loop when two bytes are in the UART buffer then it will get two bytes and output them. I suspect the 16/17 issue is just a coincidence.

Also, when there is nothing in the buffer your loop consumes 100% CPU. That's not good.

You'd be better off using the blocking `SerialPort.ReadByte()` call, get the length byte and then loop to read that many more bytes from the serial port.

Also, as a protocol, using protobuf messages alone with no header mark isn't great. If you get out of sync it could take a long while before you get lucky and get back in sync. You might want to add some kind of 'magic byte' or a sequence of magic bytes at the start of each message so the reader can regain sync.

Comment: In regards to the loop - yeah it's a very simple test app not meant to be a real use case.  For the record, I am using `SerialPort.ReadByte()` in my actual code, but for this demonstration I just happened to use it as a buffer - both fail the same way.  But it couldn't be a race condition as the serial port buffer should trap all of the bytes and this app should spit out the next set of bytes on the next loop right?  Also why would it work when I have a value of '16' or less on the int, but ALWAYS fail with a value of 17 or greater

Comment: What it it loops back before "all of the bytes" have been sent? Your PC is much faster than the Arduino, it's going to get back and see just two bytes, grab them, output, then come back and get one more.

Comment: right, that's not the problem.  if it came back and got one more then I would be receiving all of the bytes, but only two ever come across.  see my updated question for a simpler c# app that still demonstrates the problem.  again note that it's just an example, not actual production code - it's merely there to demonstrate that even at the most basic level of serial reading it only receives two bytes when all of my serial monitors show three bytes

Comment: in regards to your note about protobuf messages - again this isn't production code, I'm demonstrating a simple serial message issue not how I wrote my protobuf reader